# Excel Fomrula doesn't let me press enter and displays an error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why does this formula cause an error and prevent me from pressing enter? The individual components of the formula seem to work fine, but when combined, they do not function properly.

Here is the string:

`.cict oem liab on file exp 11/10/19`

This part of the formula is separate:

`VSTACK(TRIM(SEQUENCE(10,,0)),{" ";"/";"-"})`

Complete formula:

```
=COUNTIF(VSTACK(TRIM(SEQUENCE(10,,0)),{" ";"/";"-"}), TRIM(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)))=1
```

Error:

[image]

My Sheet

Comment: what is this: `TRIM(SEQUENCE(10,,0))` supposed to do?

Comment: Even if you were able to get it working COUNTIF will not allow the use of dyanmic arrays.  It requires a range.

Comment: I think at this point we need some test data and expected output.  The formula does not make sense.

Comment: I may not be able to explain this in words, but I have included a picture above for reference. to get desired result.

Comment: I am trying to get the complete date including `/` output would be `11/10/19`

Comment: `=FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),ISNUMBER(--(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "))))`

Comment: Thank you, @ScottCraner, for looking into this. However, I need to confirm why the above function isn't working as expected.

Comment: COUNTIF will not allow a dynamic array.  It must be a range.  That is why it fails

Comment: IF you want the TRUE/FALSE list: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)),VSTACK(TRIM(SEQUENCE(10,,0)),{" ";"/";"-"}),0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTIF will not allow the use of Dynamic Array formulas as range inputs.  It expects a range.

To get the desired TRUE/FALSE list we use MATCH():

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)),VSTACK(SEQUENCE(10,,0),{" ";"/";"-"}),0))
```

[image]

If all you want is the date then use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),ISNUMBER(--(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving this issue; it has been frustrating, and I've been trying to fix it for the past hour. Could you please provide the final result using the recent formula with TRUE and FALSE outcomes? which is `11/10/19`